# WordPress solo para manejo de rutas

Tags: html5, wordpress, drupal

Buenas necesito implementar una web HTML5 en 2 idiomas pagina.com y página.com/es. Lamentablemente cuento con un hosting que solo me permite subir los archivos a una carpeta public o utilizar WordPress o Drupal. Mi pregunta es como utilizar algún servicio de estos para manejar las rutas de la Web. Muchas gracias.

Comment: _...cuento con un hosting que solo me permite subir los archivos a una carpeta public_ Eso lo hacen casi todos los hosting. O sea,  la carpeta public es la que usas para manejar todos los dominios que tengas en el hosting. Eso no impide que tengas varias instalaciones de WP.  Una en public directamente para pagina.com y otra en otra carpeta llamada  por ejemplo `es` para la versión en español. Cuando hagas esa segunda instalación le indicas que quieres que te instale el nuevo WP en la carpeta `es` y cuando escribas `paginas.com/es` o `es.paginas.com` irás a la versión española.

Comment: En este ejemplo verás que yo tengo dos instalaciones de WP. Una está en la carpeta public directamente: http://www.deiverbum.org y otra está en una carpeta de public llamada `app` y puedo acceder a ella de dos maneras: http://www.app.deiverbum.org o bien http://www.deiverbum.org/app Es el mismo hosting, pero dos instalaciones y por tanto dos páginas web diferentes.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo mucho el Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/ , es muy facil de usar y te configura los idiomas que quieras en la misma instalación de WP, lo único es que tu mismo tienes que traducir cada texto, para mi es más completa esta forma por que tienes el control de los textos.